# Error in XML Parameter Mapping

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a stored procedure that returns xml. This result is stored in a variable (of type object) in SSIS.  This variable is passed as parameter to another stored procedure in execute sql task. The parameter mapping is done as varchar. I am getting the following error:

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "exec uspDeleteLiveRecordAfterArchival ?" failed with the following error: "An error occurred while extracting the result into a variable of type (DBTYPE_STR)".

Note: I am sure there is nothing wrong in the stored procedure as it is working fine when tested alone.

What’s wrong in this parameter mapping and how to correct this?

I searched a lot but I am not seeing any useful answers.

**Variable**

[image]

**Package**

[image]

**Parameter Mapping**

[image]

Comment: I don't think SSIS can implicitly convert an object variable to varchar.   Can you store the XML from the first procedure in a string variable instead of an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get it work with Execute SQL task so far. Now I am calling the stored procedure from a script task and assigning to a variable, until I get a better solution.

**Script Task**

```
 Public Sub Main()

    Dim tableName As String =  Dts.Variables("User::CurrentTable").Value.ToString()
    Dim sourceConnection As SqlConnection
    Dim destinationConnection As SqlConnection

    Try

        Dim cmSource As ConnectionManager
        cmSource = Dts.Connections("ADOSourceConnection")
        sourceConnection = DirectCast(cmSource.AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction), System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)

        Dim cmDestination As ConnectionManager
        cmDestination = Dts.Connections("ADOACIConnection")
        destinationConnection = DirectCast(cmDestination.AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction), System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)

        Using destinationConnection

            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
            cmd.Connection = destinationConnection
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.CommandText = "uspGetIncompleteMoveFromArchival"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableName", tableName)

            Dim result As String = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
            Dts.Variables("User::IncompleteMoveXML").Value = result

            'Release Connection'
            cmSource.ReleaseConnection(sourceConnection)
            cmDestination.ReleaseConnection(destinationConnection)

            'Success'
            Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success

        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception

        Dim exceptionVariable As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables = Nothing
        Dts.VariableDispenser.LockOneForWrite("User::ScriptException", exceptionVariable)
        exceptionVariable("User::ScriptException").Value = ex.Message
        exceptionVariable.Unlock()
        Dts.Events.FireError(-1, "Task Name", ex.Message, String.Empty, 0)
        Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Failure

    End Try


End Sub
```

**Stored Procedure Psuedo Code**

```
DECLARE @Result XML
    SELECT @Result =
    (
        SELECT
            'SKULocationsSnapShot' AS '@tableName',
            (

                SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), SnapShotID) AS SnapShotID,
                       CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), LocationID) AS LocationID
                FROM dbo.SKULocationsSnapShot CurrentTable (NOLOCK)    
                WHERE IsMoveComplete = 'N'
                FOR XML PATH('CurrentRow'), TYPE
            )
        FOR XML PATH('root')
    )

    SELECT CAST(
                    @Result
                    AS VARCHAR(MAX)
                ) AS IncompleteMoveXML
```